# ffmpeg video keep ref frame of source

Tags: ffmpeg

I like to keep the some ref frame of source (in this case ref =1):

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 6 min 19 s
Bit rate                                 : 388 kb/s
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 9.479 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.750 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.030 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.133
Stream size                              : 17.5 MiB (74%)
Language                                 : English
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

here the output

```
   ID                                       : 1
    Format                                   : AVC
    Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile                           : High@L3
    Format settings                          : CABAC  2 Ref Frames
    Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
    Format settings, Reference frames        : 2 frames
    Codec ID                                 : avc1
    Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
```

the output Ref Frames are 2 , but I like to keep to 1 or directly force to 1.

There is a way to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the encoder libx264 add `-refs 1 -bf 0`.

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `-refs` | Number of reference frames |
| `-bf` | Number of b-frames |

- `mediainfo` appears to count both reference frames and b-frames for `Format settings, Reference frames` total (but I did not verify).
- Alternatively, instead of `-refs 1 -bf 0` you can use `-preset ultrafast` which will automatically set `-refs 1 -bf 0`. However, it's not recommended as it will change many other settings too and is the least efficient (but fastest) preset.